Find the smallest  such that for all prime numbers $P_1$ and $P_2$ of size $$,$P = P_1 \cdot 10^n + P_2$ is never a prime number?
Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be two different prime numbers of size $n$, defined as:
$P_1 = a_{n-1} \cdot 10^{n-1} + a_{n-2} \cdot 10^{n-2} + \dots + a_1 \cdot 10 + a_0$
$P_2 = b_{n-1} \cdot 10^{n-1} + b_{n-2} \cdot 10^{n-2} + \dots + b_1 \cdot 10 + b_0$
$\text{where } a_i, b_i \in \{0, 1, \dots, 9\} \text{ and } a_{n-1}, b_{n-1} \neq 0$
and $P_1$ and $P_2$ are prime numbers.
They have the same size $n$, meaning they are composed of
$n$ digits.
Question:
Find the smallest $n$ such that:
$P = P_1 \cdot 10^n + P_2$  is never a prime number for any prime numbers $P_1$ and $P_2$ of size $n$.
For example, if $n = 1$, with $P_1 = 2$ and $P_2 = 3$:
$P = P_1 \cdot 10^n + P_2$
Substituting the values:
$P = 2 \cdot 10^1 + 3 = 23$
Here, $P = 23$ is a prime number.
For $n = 2$, with $P_1 = 13$ and $P_2 = 27$:
$P = P_1 \cdot 10^n + P_2$
Substituting the values:
$P = 13 \cdot 10^2 + 27 = 1327$
Here, $P = 1327$ is a prime number.
For $n = 3$, with $P_1 = 127$ and $P_2 = 103$:
$P = P_1 \cdot 10^n + P_2$
Substituting the values:
$P = 127 \cdot 10^3 + 103 = 127103$
Here, $P = 127103$ is a prime number.
Continue this process to find the smallest $n$ such that $P$ is never a prime number for any prime numbers $P_1$ and $P_2$ of size $n$.

I have a strong feeling that this $n$ does not exist...

Where is this problem from? Why do you think there will be such an $n$?

The problem is from with me; I formulated it. I think there exists such an
$$  if $a_n-1$ and $b_n-1$ are non-zero. I can also reformulate the problem differently by stating, for example, that $a_n-1$ and $b_n-1$ are greater than 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 ...or 8.

It's almost certain that there is no such $n$, but like so many conjectures in elementary number theory, it is unlikely that this can be proven in the current state of the art.  See OEIS sequence A340487.

Hello, the usefulness of this conjecture is that, if for example prime numbers of size n are very rare, and I only manage to find two prime numbers of size n, then P would necessarily be prime.

Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/478405/could-we-find-a-counterexample-to-this-conjecture-about-prime-numbers after waiting only a day, and without linking either post to the other.
